# Applying the style of the div tag to the style of all its children

Tags: html, css

```css
.div {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <p style="font-size: 50px; color: blue">text tag p</p>
  <p><span style="font-size: 30px; color: green">text span</span></p>
</div>
```

I have a `div` tag that has children, some of these children have their own children, each of which has its own style.
I want to style the `div` tag to apply this style to all its children and I don't know what to do
please direct me

Comment: `.div` --> `.div *`

Comment: You should not be using `!important` btw.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, if you do

```
.div {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    color: black !important;
}
```

You are saying "apply this code to all classes with the name `div`", you are not applying it to all real `<div>` elements.

You have to add the same class to all the element you want that class style, in your case:

```
<div class="div">
  <p class="div" style="font-size: 50px; color: blue">text tag p</p>
  <p>
    <span class="div" style="font-size: 30px; color: green">text span</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

As you will see I added `class="div"` to all elements.

To add a stile to all `div` elements you do not use the dot in front of the class, as the dot represents "classes with this name only", so it would be:

```
div {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want EVERYTHING inside the class to match your stile you have to say `.class-name *` which means "Everything within/inside this class" and it would be:

```
.class-name *{
    color: red;
}
```

Idea:

You should give a *name* to a class that clearly states what it does, like `darker-text` and use `class="darker-text"` on the element.

Idea 2:

These are the basics of CSS, I recommend you read some more on classes and ID, as it will really speed up your understanding, try here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the * selector like this:

```css
.div * {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    color: black !important;
}
```

These styles will applied on all `<div class="div"></div>` children and sub children.